# AArch64 - GNU ld - multiple linker scripts (for kernel and userland)

Tags: ld, elf, arm64, bare-metal

I have started a bare-metal application for AArch64. The bare-metal application should implement a simple kernel (for memory/device management and exception handling) and an userland which can made syscalls to output something over the UART via `printf()` as example. Currently I'm working on the kernel at EL1. The indent is to put kernel and userland in a single ELF binary, because I don't have implemented an filesystem driver and ELF support yet.

The kernel should reside at address `0xC0000000` and the main application (userland) at `0x40000000` as example. But I will change this addresses later. Is it possible to pass two linker scripts to GNU ld? I realize that I must use different sections for kernel and userland.

Or in another question:
Is my indent even possible? Okay it's maybe a generic question, but currently didn't find a similar question here.

Comment: I feel like it'd be much cleaner and easier to compile and link userland separately, use `objcopy -O binary` to get a bare metal binary, then embed that in the kernel with `.incbin` or similar...

Comment: @Siguza Thanks for the much easier solution. I didn't know `.incbin`.

Answer (score 0):

From the LD manual: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html, it's said:

```
Multiple -T options accumulate.
```

Just use it like this: -T script1.ld -T script2.ld